# Is there any third-party Push Service which can be integrated in Nodejs Server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, push-notification

I am working on a MEAN Stack project and I have setup my nodejs server to send push notifications to my hybrid app. It does work fine but now I am wondering that is there any third party solution available for push notifications? Which I can integrate it in my nodejs server and will send pushes directly from the third-party server? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of pusher
Contains example on different platforms.Easy to integrate.

[Link](https://pusher.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I used oneSignal. I loved it